# VS 2022 preview 17. 2 MAUI copyright symbol is not working

Tags: maui

I used Visual Studio 2022 preview 17.2 MAUI.
I tried to add Copyright symbol to Label and is not working.

```
<Label Text="symbol of copy right is not working"/>
```

---

Exception when Build:

```
the "xamlctask" task failed unexpectedly (MSB4018)
```

Comment: Assuming it also fails when you try `<Label Text="&copy;" TextType="Html" />`, then something seems to be fundamentally wrong in either the project or in files installed by VS for Maui. Some tests to try:  1) Remove the symbol (or the corresponding `&copy;`) from the text. Then it works?  2) Delete `bin` and `obj` folder(s) from your solution. Build again. 3) Worst case - if you updated from an earlier version of VS 2022 Preview - Uninstall VS 2022 Preview. Reboot pc. Reinstall.

Comment: 1+2 not work. 3. I reinstall vs VS 2022 Preview and is not help.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue and it didn't work even with `TextType="Html"` until I found that `&#x00A9;` also returns copyright symbol. And it works on VS 17.6.

Ex:

```xml
<Label Text="&#x00A9; 2023"/>
```

Returns *© 2023*

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML code

```
&copy;
```

So..

```
<Label Text="&copy; 2022 My Name" TextType="Html" />
```

Comment: Sorry is not work

Comment: Could you post some of your code?

Comment: I’ve updated my example to specify TextType="Html" @danies8

Comment: Is not complied in vs 20202 v17.2 MAUI

Comment: Text="Hello, ©" works here

Comment: I want copy right to be first

Comment: Can you share your code, or the error message you are seeing @danies8?

Comment: Text="©  this item"  works all so , maybe like @MikeIrving suggested show your code

Comment: I got this exception when adding ©.

Comment: The "XAMLCTask" task failed unexpecctedely (MSB4018)

Comment: Any new suggestions

Comment: can you share the full error stack from the Output window of Visual Studio?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XLS0107 The named entity '&copy;' is not defined in XAML. Client.MAUI D:\Applications\Client\Client.MAUI\LoginPage.xaml 33

Comment: Can you show us your full Line 33? @danies8

Comment: @MikeIrving It doesn't work by me either. I got error `Reference to undeclared entity 'copy'`. See my answer that works by me.